# When trying to access Magmi it is redirecting to 404 page not found

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magmi

I am trying to use Magmi for product import.
When I access **http://example.com.au/magmi/web/magmi.php** it redirect to 404 page not found.

I have give 755 permission to all the Magmi folders.

If I access **http://example.com.au/magmi/web/** there is no redirection.

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you've installed it where you're implying by the link you've given above?

Comment: @PedroKTFC example.com is dummy name here I have givenother locations are correct

Comment: I appreciate that. page not found implies that your link is wrong. When I use magmi I have it at mage/magmi/web/magmi.php. Double/triple check that you're really using the correct link (and check for typos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue from hosting provider.I contacted them they fixed from their side.

Comment: What is the error you faced, how you solved, Now I am getting the same error? How you solved this?